# XSLT Template - Add or remove nodes conditionally

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is what i need to do:

1. If Child 2 AND Child 3 exist, I need to create a `<child1.5>` node after Child 1 and remove Child 2
2. If Child 3 does not exist, i need to turn Child 2 into Child 3

Source Document

```
<parent>
  <child1>
  </child1>
  <child2>
  </child2>
 </parent>
<parent>
  <child1>
  </child1>
  <child2>
  </child2>
  <child3>
  </child3>
</parent>
```

Comment: Write templates for your conditions e.g. `<xsl:template match="parent[not(child3)]/child2"><child3><xsl:apply-templates/></child3></xsl:template>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following stylesheet/template set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent[child2 and child3]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="child1"/>
      <child1.5>
        Content
      </child1.5>
      <xsl:copy-of select="child3"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent[child2 and not(child3)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="child1"/>
      <child3>
        <xsl:value-of select="child2" />
      </child3>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is** (with a `root` element making your XML *well-formed*):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <parent><child1>
        </child1>
        <child3>
        </child3>
    </parent>
    <parent><child1>
        </child1>
        <child1.5>
            Content
        </child1.5>
        <child3>
        </child3>
    </parent>
</root>
```